# Is there a way to check and replace multiple regex matches within 1-2 lines?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to replace a substring from a read file based on the match criteria without using multiple if/elif statements.

Something like:

```
for data in csvfile:
  if(data.startswith(("a","b","c"))):
    data = re.sub(("a","b","c")), (("apple","banana","car")), data)
    print(data)
```

Output

```
apple...
banana...
car...
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what would the input/output file look like?

Comment: If a regex rule doesn't match, then `re.sub` won't make any changes to the line. Do you need the if statements at all?

Comment: Yes, I have an else statement which is needed for other cases.